# CMD/Batch - IF Condition for cURL HTTP Response Codes

Tags: http, batch-file, curl

In Batch-File, is it possible to run a cURL command and do different things depending on what HTTP Status Code is returned? Something like this:

```
curl -G "https://httpbin.org/status/404" --fail --output "output.txt" || echo Error

IF %variable% = 200 do (
echo Success
)

IF %variable% = 404 do (
echo Not Found
)

IF %variable% = 503 do (
echo Not Available
)
```

How do I obtain cURL's HTTP response code as a %variable% to do my IF checks against? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote this code which works well:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('curl -G "https://httpbin.org/status/404" -s --write-out "%%{http_code}" --fail --output "output.txt"') do set httpcode=%%a

if %httpcode% == 404 @echo Not Found
```